# Type SomeType[number] is not assignable to SomeType[number] ... hmm?

Tags: typescript, redux, typescript-generics

I'm building a function that will take a simple config and return a set of fully typed Redux 'actionCreators'.

The function is working, and I'm getting the correct type checking and autocomplete when I use the returned actionCreators. However, Typescript is not happy with one of the details, and I am struggling to work out why.

Please note - this is a work in progress, so you may see some peripheral things that could be cleaned up, but my question really is just about the error that Typescript is catching.

First I have a few types to set up - these simply define the type of TypeConfig that will be provided to the actionCreators factory.

```
interface GenericPayloads {
    [key: number]: any;
}

enum GenericEnum {};
type Enum = typeof GenericEnum;

interface GenericTypeConfig {
    payloads: GenericPayloads;
    actionTypes: Enum;
}
```

Then a generic interface that creates an interface containing the types of ActionTypes and Payloads that the actionCreators need to be typed with:

```
interface Config<ActionTypes extends Enum, Payloads extends GenericPayloads> {
    payloads: Payloads;
    actionTypes: ActionTypes;
};
```

And finally a generic interface that will be passed the Config interface that is passed into the generic function (which I will get to shortly) to create an interface that represents the type of config expected in the parameters:

```
interface ConfigAsParams<Config extends GenericTypeConfig> {
    actionTypes: Config['actionTypes'];
}
```

Then to use the factory, I simply define the action types and payloads as follows (these are just some random action type examples):

```
enum actionTypes {
    'DO_ACTION',
    'DO_ANOTHER_ACTION',
    'DO_FINAL_ACTION'
};

interface Payloads {
    [actionTypes.DO_ACTION]: {value: string};
    [actionTypes.DO_ANOTHER_ACTION]: {complete: boolean};
    [actionTypes.DO_FINAL_ACTION]: undefined;
};

type MyTypeConfig = TypeConfig<typeof actionTypes, Payloads>;
```

A quick couple of helper functions:

```
const getKeys = Object.keys as <T extends Enum>(obj: T) => Array<keyof T>;

const getNumericEnumValue = <T extends Enum>(obj: T, key: keyof T): {string: false} | {string:true,value: number} => {

    if (!isNaN(Number(key))) return {
        string: false
    };

    const value = obj[key];

    return {
        string: true,
        value: value as unknown as number
    }

}
```

And finally the function:

```
function actionFactory<Config extends GenericTypeConfig>(config: ValuesConfig<Config>) {

    const createActions = () => {

        type ActionCreators = {
            [P in keyof Config['payloads']]: (payload: Config['payloads'][P]) => {type: Config['actionTypes'][P], payload: typeof payload};
        }

        const actionCreators: Partial<ActionCreators> = {};

        for (const key of getKeys(config.actionTypes)) {

                const enumIdx = getNumericEnumValue(config.actionTypes, key);

                if (!enumIdx.string) continue;

                const keyAsString = key as string;

                const actionCreator: ActionCreators[number] = ((payload) => ({type: keyAsString, payload}));

                actionCreators[enumIdx.value] = actionCreator; // Typescript complains here
                
        };

        return actionCreators as ActionCreators; 
    }

    return createActions;
    
}
```

This function does as expected, for example I can use it as below:

```
const test = actionFactory<MyTypeConfig>({actionTypes});

const actionCreators = test();

const action = actionCreators ? actionCreators[actionTypes.DO_ACTION]({value: 'hello'}) : null;
```

I get full autocomplete, Typescript complains if I try to pass an invalid payload, which is what I want, and the correct action is returned. But I just don't understand why I'm getting an error.

If I write the function as above I get this error:

```
Type '(payload: Config["payloads"][number]) => { type: Config["actionTypes"][number]; payload: Config["payloads"][number]; }' is not assignable to type 'ActionCreators[number]'.ts(2322)
```

But more confusingly, if I specifically create the following type

```
type ActionCreator = ActionCreators[number];
```

And then assign it to the actionCreator...

```
const actionCreator: ActionCreator = ((payload) => ({type: keyAsString, payload}));
```

I get the following error:

```
Type 'ActionCreator' is not assignable to type 'ActionCreators[number]'.ts(2322)
```

It must be that I need to take an extra step somewhere to reassure Typescript of something, but I am fairly new to generics so I'm struggling to see it.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction

Comment: It seems like you might be to some extent reinventing a lot of stuff that would already be available in the official Redux Toolkit. Just in case - you might want to take a look at that if it solves your problems before you go too deep on doing that yourself - it comes with very strong TypeScript support.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @phry I will take a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I solved it.

I was trying to assign the function with a type of...

```
ActionCreators[number]
```

...to the actionCreators object which has a type of...

```
Partial<ActionCreators>.
```

To fix this, I defined the type as follows:

```
const actionCreators: Partial<ActionCreators> = {};

type ActionCreator = (typeof actionCreators)[number];
```

Then when assigning the function to the object:

```
const actionCreator: ActionCreator = ((payload) => ({type: keyAsString, payload}));

actionCreators[enumIdx.value] = actionCreator;
```

Typescript no longer complains and the actionCreators are fully typed as intended :)

The actionCreators returned by the factory are now assured, and not possibly undefined so I can use the factory as follows:

```
const test = actionFactory<MyTypeConfig>({actionTypes});

const actionCreators = test();

const action = actionCreators[actionTypes.DO_ACTION]({value: 'hello'});
```